# Python Selenium Webdriver: Unable to fetch data for all hidden elements using "textContent"

Tags: python, html, selenium, chrome-web-driver

I want to scrape data from Netflix to get the following information:
1.Show Name 
2.Season 
3.Episode Name for each of the season 
4.URL for each of the episode
5.Duration for each of the show. 
Selenium version: 3.141.0 Python version: 3.6.6, using Chrome Webdriver.

The tool is able to login in, search for the specific show and click on Episodes tab as shown below:
[Screenshot of sample episodes for a show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxQx7.png)

HTML elements Details for each episode are as follows:

```
div class="slider-item slider-item-0" 
div class="slider-item slider-item-1"
div class="slider-item slider-item-2"
div class="slider-item slider-item-3"
div class="slider-item slider-item-"
div class="slider-item slider-item-"
div class="slider-item slider-item-"
div class="slider-item slider-item-"
```

After the 4th item, other elements are hidden from the home screen

To locate the elements I am using the below code **driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='episodeTitle']//p[@class ='ellipsized']").** This gives the list of episode name for each show.

I know for locating the hidden elements we can use print demo_div.get_attribute('innerHTML')
**`driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", demo_div)`**

print demo_div.get_attribute('textContent')
**`driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent", demo_div)`**
from the below link:
https://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/
 THE ISSUE: Every time the details of last two or more episodes are missed. 
I have used both of the above techniques to get the hidden elements, but no luck
Also I have use Web driver implicit and explicit wait times but still the some episodes go missing. 
Code Snippet to get the episode name:

```
e8= driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='episodeTitle']//p[@class ='ellipsized']")
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What if you click on the arrow (on the right), then repeat the process until the arrow is not there anymore?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to get the required data by clicking on next arrow and using text attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These div are loading dynamically on the arrow click.

1. You should extract the visible items list
2. Then Click the arrow button and wait for list replacement or load
3. Extract the new list

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was able to successfully solve the problem.